# Reflection and Transmission coef. for a triple potential barrier, with different values

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, scattering

In the case where we consider a propagating material wave in a triple potential barrier region, where the potentials are of different values and they are in series one after the other, how can we find the reflection and transmission coefficients?[image]

I am familiar with the case, when we are dealing with a single potential barrier. In that case we have:

$$R=\frac{j_{ref}}{j_{inc}}$$ and $$T=\frac{j_{trans}}{j_{inc}}$$

where $j_{...}$ are the different probability density currents.

Now, when we are dealing with a situation like the one I described above, I assume (similarly as to how it happens when a light rey propagates to regions with different refractive indexes) we can consider each region individually and find the corresponding transmission $T_i$ and reflection $R_i$ coefficients. Now,my question is, should it be that in every region the following eq. must hold:$R_i+T_i=1$. I ask this, because when we are found in the region where the potential V2 is active, there we will have multiple transmitted and reflected waves. So how does this affect the above equation, and if it does, how can one talk about these coefficient in this case?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the currents, you can find the reflection and transmission coefficients. If you know the wave function, you can find the currents. If you know the boundary conditions, you can solve the Schrodinger equation for the wave function.

Since you are familiar with this kind of problem for a single potential barrier, you know that a wave function must be continuous and have a continuous derivative. Those are the boundary conditions you need to apply at each boundary between regions. You will find a reflection and transmittance at each boundary.

Comment: Can I also apply this eq. $R+T=1$ in each boundary ?

Comment: Yes. That is loosely a statement that whatever approaches the boundary must leave it. It can either leave it by reflecting and returning where it came from or passing through and continuing onward. Keep in mind that something can approach from both directions. If so, it applies separately to both incoming currents.